# Custom Label With Markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using this [link](http://www.barattalo.it/measure-distance-google-maps) to add a `Ruler` in my google map application

when i click on button `i.e` `Get Measure` then two markers with label appear on map work perfectly and it works until i am not refresh my webpage. When i refreshed my pages then again click on button the error appears is

```
InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map, and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama
```

Error occurs from this portion of code

```
function Label(opt_options)
{
// Initialization
try
{
    console.log(opt_options);
    this.setValues(opt_options); // Error Generate due to this line although its map object already i checked in console
}
catch(error)
{
    console.log(error);
}

// Label specific

var span = this.span_ = document.createElement('span');
span.style.cssText = 'position: relative; left: 0%; top: -8px; ' +
    'white-space: nowrap; border: 0px; font-family:arial; font-weight:bold;' +
    'padding: 2px; background-color: #ddd; '+
    'opacity: .75; '+
    'filter: alpha(opacity=75); '+
    '-ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=75)"; '+
    '-khtml-opacity: .75; '+
    '-moz-opacity: .75;';
var div = this.div_ = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(span);
div.style.cssText = 'position: absolute; display:none';
};
```

**Update 1**

```
// Define the overlay, derived from google.maps.OverlayView
function Label(opt_options)
{
// Initialization
try
{
    console.log(opt_options);
    this.setValues(opt_options);
}
catch(error)
{
    console.log(error);
}

// Label specific

var span = this.span_ = document.createElement('span');
span.style.cssText = 'position: relative; left: 0%; top: -8px; ' +
    'white-space: nowrap; border: 0px; font-family:arial; font-weight:bold;' +
    'padding: 2px; background-color: #ddd; '+
    'opacity: .75; '+
    'filter: alpha(opacity=75); '+
    '-ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=75)"; '+
    '-khtml-opacity: .75; '+
    '-moz-opacity: .75;';
var div = this.div_ = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(span);
div.style.cssText = 'position: absolute; display:none';
};
Label.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView;
// Implement onAdd
Label.prototype.onAdd = function()
{
var pane = this.getPanes().overlayLayer;
pane.appendChild(this.div_);

// Ensures the label is redrawn if the text or position is changed.
var me = this;
this.listeners_ = [
    google.maps.event.addListener(this, 'position_changed',
    function() { me.draw(); }),
    google.maps.event.addListener(this, 'text_changed',
    function() { me.draw(); })
];
};
// Implement onRemove
Label.prototype.onRemove = function()
{
this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_ );
// Label is removed from the map, stop updating its position/text.
for (var i = 0, I = this.listeners_.length; i < I; ++i)
{
    google.maps.event.removeListener(this.listeners_[i]);
}
};
// Implement draw
Label.prototype.draw = function()
{
var projection = this.getProjection();
var position = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.get('position'));
var div = this.div_;
div.style.left = position.x + 'px';
div.style.top = position.y + 'px';
div.style.display = 'block';
this.span_.innerHTML = this.get('text').toString();
};
```

**Update 2**

Here is the code from where Label call

```
try{
var ruler1 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: Mappy.mapObject.getCenter(),
            icon:'images/currenrLocation.png',
            map: Mappy.mapObject,
            draggable: true
        });
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(ruler1.getPosition().lat()+0.001, ruler1.getPosition().lng());
        var ruler2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: Mappy.mapObject,
            draggable: true
        });
        //alert('Marker 1 2 Created');
        var ruler1label = new Label({ map: Mappy.mapObject });
        var ruler2label = new Label({ map: Mappy.mapObject });
        //alert('Label 1 2 Created');
        ruler1label.bindTo('position', ruler1, 'position');
        ruler2label.bindTo('position', ruler2, 'position');
        //alert('Label 1 2 Binded');
        var rulerpoly = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [ruler1.position, ruler2.position] ,
            strokeColor: "#FFFF00",
            strokeOpacity: .7,
            strokeWeight: 7
        });
        //alert('Polyline Created');
        rulerpoly.setMap(Mappy.mapObject);

        ruler1label.set('text',Mappy.rulerDistance( ruler1.getPosition().lat(), ruler1.getPosition().lng(), ruler2.getPosition().lat(), ruler2.getPosition().lng()));
        ruler2label.set('text',Mappy.rulerDistance( ruler1.getPosition().lat(), ruler1.getPosition().lng(), ruler2.getPosition().lat(), ruler2.getPosition().lng()));
        //alert('');
        google.maps.event.addListener(ruler1, 'drag', function() {
            rulerpoly.setPath([ruler1.getPosition(), ruler2.getPosition()]);
            ruler1label.set('text',Mappy.rulerDistance( ruler1.getPosition().lat(), ruler1.getPosition().lng(), ruler2.getPosition().lat(), ruler2.getPosition().lng()));
            ruler2label.set('text',Mappy.rulerDistance( ruler1.getPosition().lat(), ruler1.getPosition().lng(), ruler2.getPosition().lat(), ruler2.getPosition().lng()));
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(ruler2, 'drag', function() {
            rulerpoly.setPath([ruler1.getPosition(), ruler2.getPosition()]);
            ruler1label.set('text',Mappy.rulerDistance( ruler1.getPosition().lat(), ruler1.getPosition().lng(), ruler2.getPosition().lat(), ruler2.getPosition().lng()));
            ruler2label.set('text',Mappy.rulerDistance( ruler1.getPosition().lat(), ruler1.getPosition().lng(), ruler2.getPosition().lat(), ruler2.getPosition().lng()));
        });
        }catch(error){
            alert(error);
        }

//code of Mappy.mapObject is
Mappy.mapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
//And mapOption are simple latlng position and map zoom level contained
```

Comment: There's no reference to `setMap` in that code.

Comment: `this.setValues(opt_options);` in this line opt_options is a Map Object and it works wile website load first time but after refreshed it throws exception on this line

Comment: I defined this `var ruler1label = new Label({ map: Mappy.mapObject });` and then the `function Label(opt_options)` executes @Andy

Comment: What's in `setValues`? Can you add that code?

Comment: I update full label class and i think `this.setValues()` is some google map function

Comment: That might not help, but the example link does not work for me. It doesn't update correctly.

Comment: yeah it does not help because it works fine here @MrUpsidown

Comment: `setValues` is a setter-method of `google.maps.MVCObject` , the most `google.maps`-classes inherit the methods of this class (`Label` also does). The error will occure when `opt_options`, the argument of the `Label`-constructor, contains a `map`-property whose value is not a `google.maps.Map`(or streetView). You must show more code or give a link, your current code doesn't show the call of the `Label`-constructor.

Comment: @Dr.Molle
I update my code from where i call `Label-constructor`

Comment: and what is `Mappy.mapObject` ?

Comment: `Mappy.mapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);`

Map Object

Comment: Also updated question @Dr.Molle

Comment: The problem is: as long as you only show parts of your code it's hard to determine the problem, e.g. it's important to see when and where  you call the Label-constructor and when you initialize the map. A link would be more helpful.

Comment: ok i will make it for live
Currently this all on local system